# Como mostrar tabela em retorno JSON?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Preciso, ao retornar de uma inserção passar parâmetro para uma página e carrega-la em uma `div` específica, tentei algo como isso:

```
var formData = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
    url: formURL,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

     var json = $.parseJSON(data);
     var IdContrato = json.par;

    // TABELA COM DOCUMENTOS DO CONTRATO
    $("#resultado-upload").load('pListaUpload.php',{IdContrato:IdContrato});
    // LIMPANDO CAMPOS DO FORMULÁRIO
    $("#sObservacao").val("");          
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#resultado-upload").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">REQUISIÇÃO AJAX FALHOU<br/> textStatus=' + textStatus + ', errorThrown=' + errorThrown + '</code></pre>');
    }
});
e.preventDefault();
e.unbind();
```

A página `php` que busca os dados e deveria ser mostrada é essa:

```
// Array que irá retornar o status da execução do script (JSON)
$aretorno = array();    
$aretorno["msg"] = "";
$aretorno["status"] = "";

@$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

// Checar conexão
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    $aretorno["msg"] = "Conexão ao banco de dados falhou.";
    $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
    echo $aretorno;
    exit;
}

if (!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
    $aretorno = "Erro ao carregar conjunto de caracteres utf8.";
    echo $aretorno;
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM gerDoctoContrato WHERE IdContrato = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param(
    "i",
    $_POST["IdContrato"]
);

if($stmt->execute()){
    $data = array();    
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    echo '';
    echo '
            
                Arquivo
                Tipo
                Caminho
                Ação
              
            ';
    echo '';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $IdDocumento = $row['IdDocumento'];
        $IdContrato = $row['IdContrato'];       

        echo '';
            echo '' . $row['NomeArquivo'] .'';
            echo '' . $row['TipoArquivo'] .'';
            echo '' . $row['CaminhoAnexo'] .'';
            echo '';

        echo '';
    }
    echo '';
    echo '';
    $stmt->close();
}else{
    echo "Ocorreu um erro na listagem dos dados: " . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
}

//close the database
$conn->close();
```

E no meu retorno aparece `Array`, o parâmetro consegui recuperar mas exibir a tabela não.

Comment: você já tem o valor do IdContrato ? e só não está conseguindo fazer o load da tabela, isso ?

Comment: Olá @Thiago Friedman, isso mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente fazer assim, é pra funcionar se o nome da div está correta e da página também:

```
$("#resultado-upload").load('pListaUpload.php',{'IdContrato' : IdContrato});
```

Porventura caso não funcione tenta fazer com ajax o carregamento desta maneira:

```
  var value = IdContrato;  
    $.ajax({
      url: "pListaUpload.php",
      data: "key="+value,
      type: "post",
      success: function(data){
            $('#resultado-upload').html(data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Olá @Thiago Friedman, infelizmente em nenhuma das situações funcionou.

Comment: estranho heim, seu ajax realmente está retornando success ? ou sempre cai no error ?

Comment: Olá @Thiago, quando eu uso esse código: $("#resultado-upload").html('<pre><code>'+data+'</code></pre>'); o resultado que aparece é: {"msg":"Registro inserido com sucesso.","par":"34","status":""}

Comment: Olá @Thiago Friedman obrigado pela ajuda, refiz o código novamente e agora tudo está funcionando perfeitamente.